# When is the best time to start Memcache in a php mvc?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, memcached

At the moment I'm developing my first very simple custom mvc, I'm using Memcache to cache some pdo mysql queries but I'm wondering as to when is the best time to do:

```
$memcached = new Memcache;
$memcached->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

At the moment I've been trying the following:

```
class Model {

    protected static $memcached;

     function __construct() {

        self::$memcached = new Memcache;
        self::$memcached->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
    }
}


class advancedModel extends Model {

    function __construct($key) {

        $core = Connect::getInstance();
        $data = parent::$memcached->get($key);

        if(!$data){     
            $stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':uriName', $uriName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $data = $stmt->fetch();
            parent::$memcached->set($key, $data, 0, 3600);  
        }

        //Memcache fails
       return $data; 

   }
}
```

Would it be better to somehow start it all the time or can you just call it everytime you need to store something and open a new connection like mysql connect?

Comment: "The best time" is quite subjective and specific to your application. I'd at least follow lazy principles and load and connect *the first time it's needed*, but no sooner, and then keep the connection around. To make this work you'll want to abstract the connection into an object, or at least a method. Ideally you'll want to use dependency injection for that. Writing all that up in an answer with code samples would be longer than I care to write right now though, so hopefully this'll give you an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the newer `memcached` library for PHP (http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/memcached.addserver.php) which lazy connects. This way you could instantiate the object immediately, but it wouldn't connect until you start using it.